# Understanding of Upperbound and Lowerbound in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, lower-bound, upperbound

I have this scala code:

```
class Creature {
  override def toString = "I exist"
}

class Person(val name: String) extends Creature {
  override def toString = name
}

class Employee(override val name: String) extends Person(name) {
  override def toString = name
}

class Test[T](val x: T = null) {

  def upperBound[U <: T](v: U): Test[U] = {
    new Test[U](v)
  }

  def lowerBound[U >: T](v: U): Test[U] = {
    new Test[U](v)
  }
}
```

We can see the hierarchy relationship between Creature, Person, and Employee:

```
Creature <- Person <- Employee
```

In the def main:

```
val test = new Test[Person]()

val ub = test.upperBound(new Employee("John Derp")) //#1 ok because Employee is subtype of Person
val lb = test.lowerBound(new Creature())            //#2 ok because Creature is supertype of Person

val ub2 = test.upperBound(new Creature())           //#3 error because Creature is not subtype of Person
val lb2 = test.lowerBound(new Employee("Scala Jo")) //#4 ok? how could? as Employee is not supertype of Person
```

What can I understand is:

1. `A <: B` define A must be subtype or equal to B (upper bound)
2. `A >: B` define A must be supertype or equal to B (lower bound)

But what happened to #4 ? Why there is no error? As the Employee is not supertype of Person, I expect it shouldn't conform to the bound type parameter `[U >: T]`.

Anyone can explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example may help

```
scala> test.lowerBound(new Employee("Scala Jo"))
res9: Test[Person] = Test@1ba319a7

scala> test.lowerBound[Employee](new Employee("Scala Jo"))
<console>:21: error: type arguments [Employee] do not conform to method lowerBound's type parameter bounds [U >: Person]
              test.lowerBound[Employee](new Employee("Scala Jo"))
                             ^
```

In general, it's connected to the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) - you can use subtype anywhere instead of supertype (or "subtype can always be casted to its supertype"), so type inference trying to infer as nearest supertype as it can (like `Person` here).

So, for ub2 there is no such intersection between `[Nothing..Person]` and `[Creature..Any]`, but for lb2 there is one between `[Person..Any]` and `[Employee..Any]` - and that's the `Person`. So, you should specify type explicitly (force `Employee` instead of `[Employee..Any]`) to avoid type inference here.

The example where lb2 expectedly failing even with type inference:

```
scala> def aaa[T, A >: T](a: A)(t: T, a2: A) = t
aaa: [T, A >: T](a: A)(t: T, a2: A)T

scala> aaa(new Employee(""))(new Person(""), new Employee(""))
<console>:19: error: type arguments [Person,Employee] do not conform to method aaa's type parameter bounds [T,A >: T]
              aaa(new Employee(""))(new Person(""), new Employee(""))
              ^
```

Here type `A` is inferred inside first parameter list and fixated as `Employee`, so second parameter list (which throws an error) just have only choice - to use it as is.

Or most commonly used example with invariant `O[T]`:

```
scala> case class O[T](a: T)
defined class O

scala> def aaa[T, A >: T](t: T, a2: O[A]) = t
aaa: [T, A >: T](t: T, a2: O[A])T

scala> aaa(new Person(""), O(new Employee("")))
<console>:21: error: type mismatch;
 found   : O[Employee]
 required: O[Person]
Note: Employee <: Person, but class O is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
              aaa(new Person(""), O(new Employee("")))
                                   ^
```

`T` is fixed to `Employee` here and it's not possible to cast `O[Employee]` to 
`O[Person]` due to invariance by default.

Comment: As always, great answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it happens because you can pass any `Person` to your

```
Test[Person].lowerBound(Person)
```

and as `Employee` is a subclass of `Person` it is considered as `Person` which is legal here.

Comment: But lowerbound `U >: T` indicate it expects U to be same type or supertype to T. In the case #4, T = Person, U = Employee. `Employee` is subtype of `Person` so it shouldn't get passed, or am I wrong?

Comment: `test.lowerBound[Employee](new Employee("Scala Jo")` does not work. `test.lowerBound[Person](new Employee("Scala Jo")` works.  Your code works because the compiler uses `Person` in `U` instead of `Employee`

Comment: @planetenkiller: so the `U` is actually coming from the class type `[Person]` instead of `Employee` type from `new Employee("Scala Jo")` argument?

Comment: U is coming from method. As @planetenkiller wrote compiler uses `test.lowerBound[Person](Person)`. U is a method type parameter with a restriction.

Comment: So U is coming from method type parameter where if I don't specify the type parameter on the method, it will take from the class type parameter instead, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. If You don't specify type parameter, i.e. `def lowerBound(v: T): Test[T]` in `Test[T]` then this method for `Test[Person]` will accept only `Person` or derived. If you specify `def lowerBound[T](v: T): Test[T]` in `Test[T]` then you can use arg of any type in `Test[Person].lowerBound`, for example `new Test[Person].lowerBound("string")`, because method `T` will hide class `T`.

Comment: If that's the case, the `test.upperBound(new Creature())` should also succeed too because I don't specify type parameter in the method, so the `U` should be `Person` too instead of `Creature`.

Comment: No. It will not work, because `Creature` is not a `Person` and compiler disallows this.

Comment: I'm still confused about the process. So the `[U >: T]` determines the `U` type in `(v: U)`. In the example above, I don't specify the type for the methods, so all of them are implicitly having method type `Person`, e.g. `test.lowerBound[Person](..)`. In #4, I can understand Employee is a (subtype of) Person so it's valid, so does the #3 it's not valid because Creature is not subtype of Person. But how about the case #2 `test.lowerBound(new Creature())`? `Creature` is not a `Person`, but it can pass. How to explain that?

Comment: "so all of them are implicitly having method type Person" - No. `Person` is only a restriction for `U`. "so does the #3 it's not valid because Creature is not subtype of Person" - Yes. "But how about the case #2" - Here `U` becomes `Creature` and it satisfies to `U >: T`, i.e. `Creature >: Person` so it passes.

Comment: I'm confused again ^^, you said `Person is only a restriction for U`, but you also said `Here U becomes Creature`. Isn't it the case #2 shouldn't pass because `U` (`Creature`) is not `Person` (because of the restriction of U to Person), then the case #4 shouldn't pass because `U` become `Employee` and it won't satisfy the `U >: T` (`Employee >: Person`)

Comment: "Isn't it the case #2 shouldn't pass" - It should pass because `Creature >: Person`. `U` should be equal or greater than `Person`. "then the case #4 shouldn't" - here compiler sees that it can satisfy the restiriction `U >: Person` if it upcast `Employee` to `Person` (it is always possible). So in this case `U` becomes `Person` and `Person >: Person` so it is OK.